# How do I access properties from global.asax in some other page's code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, global-asax

Imagine I have a property defined in global.asax.

```
public List<string> Roles
{
    get
    {
        ...
    }
    set
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

I want to use the value in another page. how to I refer to it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can access the class like this:

```
((Global)this.Context.ApplicationInstance).Roles
```

Comment: This idea worked for me but I had to modify your example slightly:

    ((global_asax)Context.ApplicationInstance).Roles

For some reason in my project the global.asax item had type global_asax.

Comment: It took me some time to understand why this didn't work for properties which are intended to live for the whole application time. For example: If you create "Roles" in the example above in "Application_Start" then using ApplicationInstance to access the "Roles" property can fail because there isn't only one "global application instance" for every request. To have globally existing properties in global.asax those properties must be static. The following blog post helped me a lot to understand what's going on: http://odetocode.com/articles/89.aspx

Comment: global_asax is creating a conflict. And Global type or namspace is not found . What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

It looks to me like that only depends on the session - so why not make it a pair of static methods which take the session as a parameter? Then you can pass in the value of the "Session" property from the page. (Anything which *does* have access to the HttpApplication can just reference its Session property, of course.)

Comment: Sorry, I downvoted your post. As I've been thinking about it you are totally right. I want to switch my vote to an upvote but stackoverflow won't let me anymore. Please accept my thanks instead.

Comment: @minty: Just click on the highlighted down vote and it will undo it. That may enable to you upvote afterwards.

Comment: This is a good idea, but wrapping the value in a property can help protect against miss use.  Of course if the backing variable is in the session then you still have to worry about people accessing it directly.

Comment: I've got a collection, preloaded into cache by IIS, and currently fetched and exposed as a property on the HttpApplication (global.asax). It is intended to live forever. Would you suggest the same solution, exposing it through the Session? This way? or as a `static` property on HttpApplication?

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: No, if it's not logically part of the session, then it would be odd to use the session. Sounds like a static property on the application would be reasonable.

Comment: @JonSkeet: One last thing in regards to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514606/asp-net-application-warmup-exposing-collections if you wouldn't mind. From a dev box, what does it take to configure IIS Express properly to use the preloader. Right now the property is null, and the preloader doesn't seem to be getting called.

Comment: @one.beat.consumer: Please don't add comments to mostly-unrelated comments to answers. You've asked a question and received an answer there.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a property you need to access in all pages, you might be better defining a base page which all your other pages extend...

e.g. by default

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
}
```

What you could do is add a BasePage.cs to your App_Code folder

```
public class BasePage : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
   public List<string> Roles
   {
       get { ... }
       set { ... }
   }
}
```

And then have your pages extend this.

```
public partial class _Default : BasePage
{
}
```

Comment: How would this affect the visual studio designer etc?

Answer (score 1):

Hey, I'm popping my stackoverflow.com cherry! My first answer after lurking for a month.

To access a property defined in your Global class, use either of the following:

- the Application property defined in both the HttpApplication and Page classes (e.g. Page.Application["TestItem"])
- the HttpContext.ApplicationInstance property (e.g. HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance)

With either of these, you can cast the result to your Global type and access the property you need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the following syntax:

```
((Global)HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).Roles
```

Answer (score 0):

If the values are dependent on the Session then this is actually simple using the HttpContext.Items Dictionary:

Place this code in the Global.asax to store the value:

```
Dim someValue As Integer = 5
Context.Items.Add("dataKey", someValue)
```

Let retreive it in a Page with this code:

```
Dim someValue As Integer = CType(HttpContext.Current.Items("dataKey"), Integer)
```

Here's a link that describes it in further detail: https://web.archive.org/web/20210608183011/http://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/060904-1.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On the global.asax itself for .net 3.5 I used typeof(global_asax) and that worked fine.  And, what actually lead me here was implementing the DotNet OpenID examples.  I changed some of it to use the Application cache like Will suggested.

Answer (score 0):

For other layers of project which it is not possible to have Global as a class:

```
dynamic roles= ((dynamic)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance).Roles;
if (roles!= null){
   // my codes
}
```

Just I have to be sure the Roles property in Global class never changes.
and another way is by reflection.